# How do I get a discord bot to mention a role and a user?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am trying to make a bot that, whenever someone says something, it sends a message in the channel saying that that person is there and is waiting for someone to join. However, it only prints @ne1 (the role I want it to mention) as plain text. Also, when I have it mention the user, it only writes the user ID instead of actually sending @(username).

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('ne1 here')) {
        message.channel.send('@ne1, ' + message.author + ' is online and waiting for you to join!');
    }
});

keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

What I want is for it to mention the @ne1 role and the person who used the command to run the bot. It only prints, "@ne1 571713056673890324 is online and waiting for you to join!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discord mentions (role, user, etc.) have a special format as detailed in the documentation [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-formats).

So, to mention a user you need to use their user ID `<@USER_ID>`/`<@!USER_ID>` and for a role it is similarly `<@&ROLE_ID>`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to mention a user, you must have their User ID and use the following format:
`<@USERID> or <@!USERID>`. For roles do `<@&ROLEID>` instead.

Make changes to your message to accommodate it:

```js
message.channel.send(`<@&${ROLEID}> <@${message.author}> is online and waiting for you to join!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using discord.js v12

If you want the easiest way to mention user you can use

```
message.channel.send(`@ne1, ${message.author} is online and waiting for you to join!`);
```

Also I'd use ID of role instead of just @role
You can get the ID by using @role and then just using the thing discord outputs
Usually something like <@&randomnumbers>